# modify value of variable in python program from batch file

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, batch-file

I have a python file (example.py) to run, which contains 3 variables.
I have three .txt files (var1.txt, var2.txt, var3.txt) which contains the values of each of these 3 variables.

I want to write a batch file (bfile.bat) that 
retrieves the three values from the text files,
pass these values to the variables in the python file,
and then run.

Any help would be appreciated!

-added-

Thank you. 
the thing is, there is no particular reason for the three files.

So a coworker of mine wrote this program in python (which I am new too), 
I'll say this program's name is "program.py", 
and she also made a file to show how it works, 
by setting the values of variables used in the program.py; 
which is "example.py". 
this example.py containes the values of the variables which are used in the program.py. 
But I want to use many values for these variables, 
so I wanted to make a batch file for this - which apparently is not a good idea.

So the example.py looks something like this:

```
SOUND = 'sound.wav'
TIMESTEP = 50
END = 500

program(SOUND, TIMESTEP, END)
```

and I want to change the values of SOUND, TIMESTEP, END.
please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: What can't you get the values from the text files with python?

Comment: I am new to python so I'm trying to figure out this problem the best way! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using input parameters in your python file, making use of `sys.argv`. Then use bash output pipelining to pipe your information to your python script. However, I do not recommend modifying the python file from bash, by writing to it.

[Also, why is it not possible to read the files with python?]

//EDit: Regarding the new information.

So when you already got a python script, this is the best thing for you to happen, as you now have multiple ways of dealing with this.

First of all, a python script can import another python script, or just parts of it. So what you can do is `import <function> from program` or `import program` and then use it. Now you can write your own python script, using her function!
You can simple create a list of your parameters and values. For example a list of tuples:

```
import program

# of course you can also generate this list, depeding on which couples of parameters
# you want to run :)
# this was hardcoding it for simplicity!
myparams = [('sound1.wav', 30, 50), ('sound2.wav', 20, 100), ...]

for (p1, p2, p3) in myparams:
    program.function(p1, p2, p3)
```

This will use the `function()` out of your `program.py`.
You could also import the program and write your own script using it with `sys.argv` so you could run it from bash using command line parameters `python myprogram.py p1 p2 p3`.
However, looking at the question, you seem to be working with Windows and writing a simple python script is probably better/easier/more convenient. But that depends on your experience on that matter :)

Cheers!

Comment: I am new to both batch file scripting and python, so if there are any better ways to do this, I am happy to listen.

Comment: @hame Well it would be best, if you would tell us more about your problem :) The best way would be to read the files with python. But why are there 3 files? Are you allowed to read it?

Comment: @hame Hey, please consider my new answer and I try to help you further :)

Comment: Thank you!! I haven't got the chance to try it out yet, but it seems comprehensible for me so far :D I am working on Linux, but I'll try to make it work !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like passing arguments would be an easier way to accomplish what you want. So instead of using files to hold the variables, try:

```
import sys

numArgs = len(sys.argv)
# You want 3 variables, and the 0th index will be '[file].py'.
if (numArgs >= 4):
    SOUND = sys.argv[1]
    TIMESTEP = sys.argv[2]
    END = sys.argv[3]
else:
    print 'Not enough arguments.'
```

Then you can simply run:

```
python [file].py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Aha, that's how the sys.argv is used.  thank you for the information!! :D